# How can I take multiple inputs from the same line?

Tags: ruby, input

I can't figure out how to take multiple inputs from one line. Here is an example:

```
p=gets.chomp().to_i
q=gets.chomp().to_i
puts"#{p} #{q}"
```

When I run this and take inputs, I have to take it from a new line. E.g.,

```
3
4
output:
3 4
```

If I type

```
3 4
```

it is not taking `4` as input and is waiting for another input from the next line. What should be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gets` reads in the whole line. If you want to process multiple elements from it, you need to `split` on that line, or perform regex matches on it, etc. In your case:

```
p, q = gets.split.map(&:to_i)
```

BTW, in your code, the `chomp` calls are superfluous, since `to_i` will work correctly whether the string ends with a newline or not.

Answer (score 0):

You **need to read as many inputs** as you can for example you need to read three numbers or more as you need from the user by using:

```
number_1, number_2, number_3, .... = gets.split.map(&:to_i)
```

As you know `gets` **Method to read a line of input**. and the `split` **method splits the string obtained from `gets` into an array of substrings** based on whitespace by default. So, if the input is something like "10 20 30" or more numbers, the `split` method would return an array ["10", "20", "30", ...]. `map(&:to_i)`: This part maps each element of the array obtained from `split` to its corresponding integer value. `to_i` is a method that converts a string to an integer. The `&:to_i` is a shorthand syntax in Ruby called a Symbol-to-Procedural Object Conversion. It converts the symbol `:to_i` into a block, which is then passed to `map`. Essentially, it's a concise way of saying "Apply the `to_i` method to each element of the array".

Now if you run this code:

```
number_1, number_2 = gets.split.map(&:to_i)
puts "#{number_1} #{number_2}"
```

You just need to write:

`3 4`

in the same line with space and the output will be:

`3 4`